# Problem: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details

Tags: java, android

Hi guys I have this warning on my code.

> H:\Project\WhatsApp2\app\src\main\java\com\example\whatsapp2\ContactsFragment.java:
>   uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked
>   for details.

My Code is given below

```
package com.example.whatsapp2;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class ContactsFragment extends Fragment {
    private View ContactsView;
    private RecyclerView myContactsList;
    private DatabaseReference ContactsRef, UsersRef;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private String currentUserID;

    public ContactsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        ContactsView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts, container, false);
        myContactsList = ContactsView.findViewById(R.id.contacts_list);
        myContactsList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        ContactsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Contacts").child(currentUserID);
        UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        return ContactsView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Contacts>().setQuery(ContactsRef,Contacts.class).build();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Contacts,ContactsViewHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Contacts, ContactsViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ContactsViewHolder contactsViewHolder, int i, @NonNull Contacts contacts) {
                String userIDs = getRef(i).getKey();
                UsersRef.child(userIDs).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("image")){
                            String userImage = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();
                            String profileStatus = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();
                            String profileName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                            contactsViewHolder.userName.setText(profileName);
                            contactsViewHolder.userStatus.setText(profileStatus);
                            Picasso.get().load(userImage).placeholder(R.drawable.profile_image).into(contactsViewHolder.profileImage);
                        } else {
                            String profileStatus = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();
                            String profileName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                            contactsViewHolder.userName.setText(profileName);
                            contactsViewHolder.userStatus.setText(profileStatus);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public ContactsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.user_display_layout,viewGroup,false);
                ContactsViewHolder viewHolder = new ContactsViewHolder(view);
                return viewHolder;
            }
        };
        myContactsList.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    public static class ContactsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView userName, userStatus;
        CircleImageView profileImage;
        public ContactsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            userName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_profile_name);
            userStatus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_staus);
            profileImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.users_profile_image);
        }
    }
}
```

What should I do to solve this problem ? Can you help me how to solve this error?

Answer (score 2):

I know this does not directly answer your question, but you can add following lines to your `build.gradle`.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        ....
    }
    ...
}

<!--  Add the lines below to get more details about that warning --> 
allprojects {
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
        }
    }
}
```

Sync your project and build it again. This will gives you more details about that warning. Then, you can narrow your search for a fix knowing the issue.

Just add that to the project's `build.gradle`:

```
project
   | - build.gradle --> add here
   | - app
        | - src
             | - main
             | - res
             | - build.gradle -> Don't add here
```